# Find all solutions of $\cos (x) + 1/2 \sec (x) = -3/2$ in the interval $(2\pi, 4\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

Find all solutions of $\cos (x) + 1/2 \sec (x) = -3/2$ in the interval $(2\pi, 4\pi)$ (Leave your answers in exact form and enter them as a comma-separated list.)

Comment: Holly, please add what you have tried, the source of the question and where you got stuck.

Comment: I've turned it into an equation and solved for cox (x) = -1/2, -1.  I don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} \cos (x) + 1/2 \sec (x) = -3/2 & \iff \cos x + \dfrac 32 + \dfrac{1}{\cos x} = 0 \\ \\
& \iff \cos^2 x + \frac{3\cos x}{2} + \frac 12 = 0\end{align}$$

Substituting $\cos x = u$ gives us a quadratic in $u$:

$$\begin{align} u^2 + \frac {3u}{2} + \frac 12 & = 0 \\ \\
u^2 + 2\cdot \frac{3}{4} u + \frac 9{16} - \frac 1{16} & = 0 \\ \\ 
\left(u + \frac 34\right)^2 - \frac 1{16} & = 0 \\ \\
\left(u +\frac 34 - \frac 14\right)\left(u +\frac 34 + \frac 14\right) & = 0 \\ \\
\left(u + \frac 12\right)\left(u + 1\right) & = 0 \\ \\
u = \cos x =  -\frac 12, \;\text{or}\; u = \cos x = -1
\end{align}$$

Now, we find two solutions $x = \cos^{-1}(-1/2) \in (2\pi, 4\pi)$, and one satisfying $x = \cos^{-1}(-1)\in (2\pi, 4\pi)$

...knowing that $\cos(2\pi/3 + 2n\pi) = \cos(4\pi/3 + 2n\pi) = -1/2$,
and that $\cos(\pi + 2n\pi) = -1$, for $n \in \mathbb Z^+$.

Comment: This needs a TU! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Recall that $\sec{x} = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$, so

$$\frac{-3}{2} = \cos(x) + \frac{1}{2 \cos{x}}$$

$$\implies \frac{-3\cos{x}}{2} = \cos^2{x} + \frac{1}{2}$$

Substitute $u = \cos{x}$ to get

$$\frac{-3u}{2} = u^2 + \frac{1}{2}$$

which is now a quadratic equation.

Comment: So cos (x) = -1/2 or cos (x) = -1 right?  I don't know where to go from there to find a solution.

Comment: Note that $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})=\frac{-1}{2}$, $\cos(\pi)=-1$, and $\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x)$.